# Stuck on splash screen at boot on Acer Aspire E15

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Freya alongside Windows 8.1 on a new Acer Aspire E15 (specs below):

Intel Celeron N2830 2.16 GHz Processor (1 MB Cache)
4 GB DDR3L SDRAM

The install went fine. When I reboot and select elementary OS in grub, it loads the elementary splash screen and then gets stuck.

When I hit the left nav button when the splash screen gets stuck, the last line says: 
[  20.427979] dw_dmac INTL9C60:00: invalid resource

Does that give any clues?

Please help.

Comment: **Hint:** Press the Left or Right navigation key while the splash screen is on and you'll see exactly what's stopping it once it's stopped. Then, edit your question, let us know about what's stopping it and we can give you a concrete answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the Solution:**

Because you already installed elementary OS only the second step is important for you.

- When you boot the live system, move your selection to 'Try elementary OS without installing', then press 'E' on your keyboard (for editing the boot options).
  Move the cursor to the line where it says "Linux ....... splash screen" at the end of the line insert a space and then write 'modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core'.
  Hit F10 for booting. Now install elementary OS and reboot.
- Turn on your notebook and do all the updates (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade).
  Next open a terminal and write 'sudo nano /etc/default/grub', go to the line where it says 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"' and change it to 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core"'. On your keyboard press 'Control + X', then 'Y' and 'Enter' to save and exit. Now write 'sudo update-grub' in the terminal.

Reboot and you should be done!

Comment: If you're interested in what you have changed on your computer read this:
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-dma-and-pio/

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain to us what does the change to `/etc/default/grub` do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with an Acer Aspire E15.

Go to more options (not sure how its exactly called) in Grub and try to boot with an older Kernel version. This helped me for some time but then again I couldn't boot at all.

After that I installed Freya in Legacy mode (BIOS), now and also before it isn't shutting down fully, which affects the whole system but at least I can boot normally. Maybe somebody else with more knowledge about Linux can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Aspire E15 E5-573G-531D laptop (with WIndows 10) and I was originally unable to boot from CD/DVD/USB stick, but I've now solved it and here's how ...

Obviously, first ensure you're using a DVD/CD/USB stick which is bootable (i.e. that you were able to boot from on a different computer).

Before you can boot from DVD/CD/USB stick, you need to access the BIOS. To do this, reboot the laptop and keep pressing F2 until BIOS is displayed. In BIOS, go to the boot menu and do several things:-
1.  Put "Windows boot manager" low down the boot order (e.g. just before network boot).
2.  Put whatever device you want to boot from high up the boot order (e.g. position 1).
3.  Switch from “UEFI” to “Legacy” boot mode.
Now save changes and exit BIOS. When the laptop restarts, you'll get some DOS text with the GUID and MAC address and after a short wait it’ll say “exiting PXE ROM” and will then boot from the CD/DVD/USB stick .... Voila!

(Now do whatever you want to from the DVD/CD/USB stick as you want).

(NB: If you're running an app to Wipe unused space on HDD - if that's why you needed to boot from DVD/CD/USB stick - ensure you don't accidentally delete the boot partition(s) which are marked “Primary Unknown”. I deleted several of these partitions by mistake and couldn't restart the computer afterwards, so don't make that mistake).

Now, having run your DVD/CD/USB stick app, you'll want to put the laptop back the way it was so that'll it start Windows as before. To do this, first shut down (not reboot) the laptop. Wait for the lights to go off. Now switch computer on and keep pressing F2 until BIOS is displayed. In BIOS, go to the boot menu and:-
1. Switch from “Legacy” to "UEFI" boot mode.
2. Disable secure boot (It won't boot with secure boot enabled).
Now save changes and exit BIOS. It will now restart and run Windows as before. Voila!